# if elseif indie while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, if-statement

I am trying to handle a CSV file via php, and I have it working. But there is this one array that I need to change based on a set of conditions.

```
$file_handle = fopen($path, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 100000);
    if($currency == "US"){
        $line_of_text[6] = str_replace ("if_you_find_this","change_to_this",$line_of_text[6]);
        $line_of_text[6] = str_replace ("if_you_find_this","change_to_this",$line_of_text[6]);
    } elseif($currency == "DE"){
        $line_of_text[6] = str_replace ("if_you_find_this","change_to_this",$line_of_text[6]);
        $line_of_text[6] = str_replace ("if_you_find_this","change_to_this",$line_of_text[6]);
}else {
        echo "Something with currency handling went wrong. Please contact support.";
}
    $data .=  $line_of_text[0] . "," . $line_of_text[1] . "," . $line_of_text[2] . "," . $line_of_text[4] . "," . $line_of_text[6] . "," .  $line_of_text[49] . "," .  $line_of_text[51] . "\n";

}
fclose($file_handle);

$new_file_handle = fopen($path, "w");
fwrite($new_file_handle, $data);
```

It's not throwing any errors, but seems that the whole conditional block is being ignored. Help?

Comment: forgot to paste in an important line that is already in the working file --> 
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 100000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading from `$file_handle` anywhere.  `feof($file_handle)` will never be true.  As posted, this code should loop forever.

(BTW, using `feof` like this is generally not how you want to do it, for this reason among others.  Better would be something like `while (($line = however_you_read($file_handle)) !== FALSE)`.)  Pretty much all the stream-reading functions return `FALSE` on any error, or on EOF.)

Answer (score 0):

Check file is correctly opened or no.
Write that code in try catch, so if any error then you can find it.
I think you file doesn't contain anything or it doesn't open successfully.